# How can A imply B and B imply A and yet A and B are not equivalent?

Tags: alloy

Below is an Alloy model that constrains a set of numbers to be positive and even. I show two ways (two predicates) to implement the constraints. I believe the two ways are equivalent (the sets that both predicates produce are the same).

To test that the two predicates are equivalent, I created one assert which says this:

```
defining_property => generate_set_members
```

Checking that assert produced no counterexamples.

Then I created an assert which says this:

```
generate_set_members => defining_property
```

Checking that assert also produced no counterexamples.

Finally, I created an assert using `iff`:

```
defining_property iff generate_set_members
```

Checking that produced a counterexample. The counterexample is set of numbers containing both positive and negative even numbers.

Huh?

How can `A => B` and `B => A` be true but `A iff B` be false?

```
one sig PositiveEven {
     elements: set Int 
}

/*
    To be in the set, a member must have these two properties:
    - it must be be positive 
    - it must be even
*/
pred defining_property {
    PositiveEven.elements = {i: Int | i >= 0 and (rem[i,2] = 0)}
}

/*
    0 is in the set
    If i is in the set, then i+2 is in the set
    Nothing else is in the set
*/
pred generate_set_members {
    0 in PositiveEven.elements
    all i: PositiveEven.elements - 0 | i.minus[2] in PositiveEven.elements
    // Create a complete set of positive even elements
    all i: Int | i.minus[2] in PositiveEven.elements => i in PositiveEven.elements
}

assert equivalent_constraints {
    //defining_property iff generate_set_members
    //defining_property => generate_set_members
    generate_set_members => defining_property
}

assert only_positive_even_numbers {
  //generate_set_members => 
  defining_property => 
    all i: Int | i in PositiveEven.elements <=> i >= 0 and i.rem[2] = 0
}

run defining_property
run generate_set_members
check equivalent_constraints
check only_positive_even_numbers
```

Comment: Could you post the full spec please? I'm getting counterexamples for both assertions you provided.

Comment: Hi @Hovercouch, I included my complete Alloy file. See above. Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: 0 isn't positive

Comment: Ha! I new someone would point that out. I figured it is easier to say positive than non-negative integers. Thanks @JonMark Perry.

Comment: @RogerCostello with the new spec, I'm still getting counterexamples for `equivalent_contraints`, for both `A => B` and `B => A`. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi @Hovercouch. In assert equivalent_constraints I have this line uncommented: generate_set_members => defining_property. When I run the command - check equivalent_constraints - I get the output: No counterexample found. You are saying that when you uncomment that line and run the command, you get counterexamples? Hmm, I don't understand. I am running alloy4.2_2015-02-22.jar on a Windows machine. Could our differing results be due to using different versions of Alloy?

Comment: @RogerCostello was able to reproduce, trying to see if I can figure out why there's a bug in 4.2_2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this in 4.2_2015-02-22, but not on 4.2. As far as I can tell, it's a bug in how 4.2_2015 translates the Kodkod representation into a SAT problem. You can reproduce this by changing the SAT solver to "output CNF to file" and running the same spec on both 4.2 and 4.2_2015, then running SAT4J on both .cnf files. The 4.2 will have 72 clauses and be satisfiable (finds an error), while the 4.2_2015 cnf will have 66 clauses and be unsatisfiable. 4.2 is the stable version while 4.2_2015 is experimental, so switching back should fix this for now.

Comment: That is a fantastic piece of detective work. Thank you @Hovercouch (are you one of the Alloy developers?) Which is the more recent version: 4.2 or 4.2_2015-02-22? Should I switch to the 4.2 version?

Comment: @RogerCostello 4.2 is older, but it's the stable version while 4.2_2015 is experimental. 2015 does not add anything to the language itself, so I'd recommend switching back for the time being. I'm not one of the developers, but I really enjoy formal methods and Alloy is one of my faves :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hovercouch. I downloaded 4.2 and will use that from now on. Oh my, it gives quite different results for my Alloy model. I reckon that I need to figure out why generate_set_members doesn't do what I thought it should do.

Comment: We're trying to create a Github site with the source. Since Alloy requires a Java VM it is hassle to install on MacOS. Therefore, there is a release on https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy for Mac although we're not ready for an official release. @Hovercouch can you help find this bug (if it is in the current source code?)

Comment: I think this is a problem with the Int handling. In 4.2_2015-02-22 there has been some optimisation concerning ints, among which to handle overflows. This is however not working well imho, Since Int is limited (-8,+7 for 4 bit) adding plus implies you get > 7.

Comment: Please file at least a bug on the  github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy site

Comment: @PeterKriens bug filed